# No Availability Zones available in Azure North Central US Region

Tags: azure, azure-vpn, availability-zone, azure-public-ip

I'm deploying a global networking solution and using Terraform as my IaC solution.  I have ExpressRoutes, VPN Gateways, Vnet-to-Vnet connections etc.

I've deployed a VPN Gateway in Azure North Central US and now when I come to deploy and IP address for it I can't.  By default I use Zone-Redundant availability zones.  Ie. Zone 1, 2 and 3.  When I try to deploy an IP using Terraform, I can't use any of the available options - no zone string list, no single zone, not the *No-Zone* or *None* parameter.  All I get is an error from the MS API saying the available zones for the region are ''.  It's literally empty.

If I deploy it manually then get the IP properties of the address it shows the zones as an empty array.  Are MS experiencing issues right now?  I find it incomprehensible that the North Central US zone which is the regional pair of South Central US (which has 3 availability zones) has...**no zones**.  I'm confused.  Could someone share their experiences please, and advise whether this is a temporary issue.  I scoured the internet and found nothing.  I'm normally working in the European Azure regions so this is the first time I've used this particular one.

Comment: This is a really bad state of affairs.  A VPN Gateway IP must have zones configured.  I can't deploy a gateway to North Central US, can't leverage the pairing for BC/DR, I have to change my ExpressRoute VXC and all my network peerings and Terraform all to transition to Azure Central.  I don't know what the politics is behind this but it was 12 years ago North Central (Illinois) was first opened.  And in 12 years MS couldn't pair it with at least one other datacenter.  I'm dumbfounded.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there are no availability zones present for North Central US in Azure but as per the [document here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/geographies/#geographies), availability zones will be coming soon for North Central US. As of now, [these are](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/availability-zones/az-region#azure-regions-with-availability-zones) the Azure Regions with Availability zones.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"Coming Soon" LoL it is now 2023
I'm not holding my breath.
They are making them available in Israel now.
I bet the new East US3 will have them from the git-go too.